# How to "SELECT WHERE" in mongodb with MongoDB driver

Tags: c#, json, mongodb

Suppose I have database named GSCADB and collection named GSCALogs, and each documnet looks like:

```
{
    "_id": "5d6f514c19038b8b38aec8d7",
    "SHA-256": "839c95cb99e8243d762ccb6f33ed8e1550b6848f739556e71dc8bcf684a159c5",
    "File Name": "Settings.settings",
    "File Name (GUID)": "69AA3BA5-D51E-465E-8447-ECAA1939739A",
    "New File Name": "Settings.settings",
    "File Size (Bytes)": "1379",
    "Result": "Ok",
    "File type": "settings",
    "True File type": "txt;htm;html",
    "Start Job Date": "2019-09-04T05:53:43.397Z"
}
```

and I want to know how many documents have Rsult as OK.

For now I have:

```
IMongoDatabase db = dbClient.GetDatabase("GSCADB");
var collection = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("GSCALogs");
```

How can I proceed? should I create some object? how the class of this object should look like?

I mean like [here](https://mongodb-documentation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ecosystem/tutorial/use-linq-queries-with-csharp-driver.html), there is C# object named `Employee`, and also [in this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40164908/mongodb-and-c-sharp-find) there is object named `User`, should I create an object also?

Comment: A simple websearch for _select where mongodb c#_ brought forth https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40164908/mongodb-and-c-sharp-find . Please do a minimum piece of research before opening a new question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB and C# Find()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40164908/mongodb-and-c-sharp-find)

Comment: @MarkusDeibel I already know this link, in this link there is object named `User` please read my question.

Comment: The answers to the linked question explicitly list the `Find` and `Filter` methods. That's what you are looking for. In addition https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/count/index.html has the info on the Mongo internal count operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try

```
// Define the filter
var filter = new BsonDocument("Result", "Ok");

// Run the count method on the collection filtering for the required docs
var documentCount = collection.CountDocuments(filter);
```

This only gives you the count. If you need the docs as well you can

```
var countedDocuments = collection.Find(filter).ToList();
```

Additional info on the available `Count` methods (depending on your driver version) can be found at https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.9/apidocs/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_MongoCollectionBase_1.htm