# C# query basic BSON knowing only key and values using LINQ

Tags: c#, json, mongodb, linq, bson

I have MongoDB collection from which I would like to query documents knowing only names of the keys.

I cannot use hardcoded base class because amount on keys will change over time in runtime. But as user I will know the names of them.

I tried doing it like that:

```
        var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(mongoCollectionName);
        List<BsonDocument> list = (from c in collection.AsQueryable<BsonDocument>()
                                   where c.GetElement("serial").Value == 1
                                   select c).ToList();
```

but with that i get {document}.GetElement("serial").Value is not supported

So is there a way to use linq to query basic BSONs ?

Thanks !

Comment: if the `BsonDocument` class has a `Serial` property, then you could do this `where c.Serial == 1`

Comment: If I understand you correcly. You only have the name `serial` at runtime. In this case you can use a `Builder` instead. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40164908/mongodb-and-c-sharp-find). Don't think you can use LINQ.

Answer (score 1):

Just make the viewModel same as the properties in MongoDb.
and For getting serial column whose value is 1, just do like this,

```
public class ViewModel {
    .... model Properties goes here
}

var SerialNo = 1;
var collection = mongoDatabase.GetCollection<ViewModel>("name of your collection");
var builder = Builders<ViewModel>.Filter;
builder.Eq(x => x.serial, SerialNo );
```

Comment: As it is written above i dont have all keys. Keys will change over time (Added/Deleted) so it is not possible to hardcode base class as it was also written above.

Answer (score 0):

Is it necessary to use LINQ? I mean it is not possible for you to do something like this?

```
var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(mongoCollectionName);
List<BsonDocument> list = collection.Find(Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("serial", 1)).ToList();
```

or even convert it to Dictionary.