# Get last record using C# MongoDB driver

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am using the mongo driver for a API. The name of my db is "EventsDb". I need to insert an entity that I have and that is "Event". I need to return the last register of the mongo db:

```
        T IRepository<T>.Add(T entity)
        {
            try
            {
                this.mongoCollection.InsertOne(entity);
                var response = this.mongoCollection.Find<Event>("EventsDb").limit(1).sort();
                return response;

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException(e.ToString());
            }
        }
```

This is the problem I am having:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>
> Error CS1929  'IMongoCollection' does not contain a definition for
> 'Find' and the best extension method overload
> 'IMongoCollectionExtensions.Find(IMongoCollection,
> FilterDefinition, FindOptions)' requires a receiver of type
> 'IMongoCollection' Events.Repositories

How do I fix this error?

Comment: Why are you throwing a `NotImplementedException` from a method that has been implemented?

Comment: For now it was just to prove and I still did not implement the correct exception but the problem is not there

Comment: I'm aware the problem isn't there.  That part of the code just doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB and C# Find()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40164908/mongodb-and-c-sharp-find)

Comment: You will need to use a Filter to go with the Find or a lambda expression

Comment: is your goal to return the entity you just inserted? or do you want to return whatever the last last entity that was inserted to the collection (probably by another thread)?

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution for this problem I added a librarie

```
using MongoDB.Driver.Linq;
```

And after

```
    public T Add(T entity)
    {
        try
        {
            this.mongoCollection.InsertOne(entity);
            var response = this.mongoCollection.AsQueryable().OrderByDescending(c => c.Id).First();
            return response;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException(e.ToString());
        }
    }
```