# How to use Mongo Find in C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm trying to query my mongo collection by a given ID.

My class is called AppInfo.cs

```
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
[Serializable]
public class AppInfo
{

    public AppInfo()
    {
    }
    [BsonId] public Guid AppId { get; set; }

}
```

the data is stored like this in Mongo
[image]

I've tried suggestions from this post [MongoDB and C# Find()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40164908/mongodb-and-c-sharp-find) but my results results is always empty.
Attempt 1 using Builders.Filter

```
var collection = _client.GetDatabase(account).GetCollection<AppInfo>("Runtime.Core.AppInfo");
var filterId = Builders<AppInfo>.Filter.Eq("_id", appId);
var appInfoList = (await collection.FindAsync(filterId)).ToList();
```

Attempt 2 using linq

```
var collection = _client.GetDatabase(account).GetCollection<AppInfo>("Runtime.Core.AppInfo");
var appInfoList = (await collection.FindAsync(x => x._id == appId)).ToList();
```

I know the value exists because if I query with no filters and then use c# to check the collection, that works.

```
var collection = _client.GetDatabase(account).GetCollection<AppInfo>("Runtime.Core.AppInfo");
var appInfoList = (await collection.FindAsync(FilterDefinition<AppInfo>.Empty)).ToList();
if (appInfoList.Any(x => x.AppId ==  new Guid("7c1348cc-105c-4e6d-ada6-45281b9c3dc0")))
{
    // this code will hit
}
```

Comment: Hi, what is the type of `appId`?

Comment: @YongShun it's a Guid